# How to provide multiple options to link a function

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I have 3 object files :

```
main.o

general.o

specific.o
```

in main.o there is a call to function :   `void handle(void)`,
general.o implement a generic functionality to   `handle()` ,
specific.o might or might not have an implementation to   `handle()` ,
I want to specify in my cmake that "search to link handle with specific.o if fail then try with general.o"

Is that possible ?

Comment: ODR violation _"...One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used (see below) is required to appear in the __entire program__ ..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition  _"...the compiler is not required to diagnose this violation, but the behavior of the program that violates it is undefined...."_  So if `void handle(void)` is in both `specific.o` and `general.o` we have Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but you could build `general` and `specific` as dynamic libraries (one for each), then load them at runtime to see what symbol(s) they export.  Them, based on what you find, your program can decide which one it wants to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There certainly is nothing in standard C++ which allows this.

For Gcc/clang toolchain you can define `handle` as a weak symbol in `general` TU with `__attribute__((weak))` and as ordinary symbol in `specific`.

Be very careful with this though, ensure that `handle` itself is not called in `general`. Because if it is, the call might be inlined before the linker sees anything, resulting in *some* code calling the general method, the rest specific. Link-time optimization might be actually more safe here.

Comment: This works great. in general I marked the function as "weak" , if I build my main only with general then it takes the function from general , if i build with both general & specific then it takes the function from specific. Thanks

Comment: @TomerAyun Nice, just be safe about not calling it from `general` as I said. Or do and see how it breaks if you force inlining in `general`. This is how syscall are usually defined, so other than that issue, the feature should be safe and stable.